# HDMI Audio not working with Raspberry 3 B and Raspbian Buster

Tags: pi-3, audio, hdmi

Volume control says "No volume control on this device"
When trying to force output to 3.5 or HDMI in raspi-config, it fails with error "There was an error running option..."

When running update in raspi-config, it says:

```
ALSA lib conf.c:3956:(snd_config_update_r) Cannot access file /usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf
ALSA lib control.c:1375:(snd_ctl_open_noupdate) Invalid CTL default
amixer: Control default open error: No such file or directory

ALSA lib conf.c:3956:(snd_config_update_r) Cannot access file /usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf
ALSA lib control.c:1375:(snd_ctl_open_noupdate) Invalid CTL default
amixer: Control default open error: No such file or directory

ALSA lib conf.c:3956:(snd_config_update_r) Cannot access file /usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf
ALSA lib control.c:1375:(snd_ctl_open_noupdate) Invalid CTL default
amixer: Control default open error: No such file or directory

Hit:1 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian buster InRelease
Hit:2 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
raspi-config is already the newest version (20191021).
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpam-systemd : Depends: systemd (= 241-7~deb10u2+rpi1) but 241-7~deb10u1+rpi1 is to be installed
 systemd : Depends: libsystemd0 (= 241-7~deb10u1+rpi1) but 241-7~deb10u2+rpi1 is to be installed
 udev : Depends: libudev1 (= 241-7~deb10u1+rpi1) but 241-7~deb10u2+rpi1 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: have you run any of the suggested fixes displayed at the bottom of the output?

Comment: @JaromandaX I did. I have also reinstalled libasound2-data and the errors are gone, though I still don't have sound and the volume control says "No volume control on this device"

Answer (score 0):

Ok, solved the issue by reinstalling  libasound2-data and setting up Preferences > Audio Device Settings. You should click Select Controls, choose PCM, and then volume control will be enabled